# What do the mask bits for newlocale(3) mean, specifically?

Tags: c, locale

The man page for **newlocale**(3) says in part:

```
The mask is the logical OR of the following:

LC_COLLATE_MASK   Collation  
LC_CTYPE_MASK     Character type  
LC_MESSAGES_MASK  Messages
LC_MONETARY_MASK  Monetary
LC_NUMERIC_MASK   Numeric
LC_TIME_MASK      Time
LC_ALL_MASK       The logical OR of all of the above
```

but it doesn't say what each of the mask bits actually *means* specifically.  In my case, I need the localized strings for `AM_STR`, `PM_STR`, month abbreviations (`ABMON_1`, ...), full month names (`MON_1`, ...), weekday abbreviations (`ABDAY_1`, ...), and full weekday names (`DAY_1`, ...).

As an educated guess, I think I need `LC_MESSAGES_MASK` -- but do I also need `LC_TIME_MASK`?

Comment: @CarlNorum: yes and I apparently *do* need `LC_TIME_MASK`. But I want to ensure that this is indeed the correct answer (or should be) across all platforms as opposed to a particular quirk that may exist on my platform (which happens to me Mac OS X).

Comment: What other platforms do you care about?  Linux doesn't have `newlocale(3)` as far as I can tell.

Comment: You need LC_TIME_MASK; you don't need LC_MESSAGES_MASK for your stated requirements.  LC_MESSAGES controls error messages, not time formatting.  To see what the 'unmasked' names such as LC_TIME mean, consult the man page for `setlocale(3)`.  They are standard C.

Comment: @CarlNorum: newlocale(3) exists on two different Linux systems I have access to.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks! (If your answer were an actual "answer" in the stackoverflow sense, I'd mark your answer as _the_ answer.

Comment: Oh ok. My linux machine may very well be old & busted.  Good to see you got the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Your wish is my command :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `LC_TIME_MASK`; you don't need `LC_MESSAGES_MASK` for your stated requirements.

`LC_MESSAGES` controls error messages, not time formatting. To see what the 'unmasked' names such as `LC_TIME` mean, consult the man page for [`setlocale(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setlocale.html). They are standard C (though the POSIX page linked to includes some extensions — notably the `"POSIX"` locale).

Answer (score 0):

You can find a detailed description of locales in POSIX, [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07)

The different types are defined

1. LC_CTYPE 
   Character classification and case conversion.
2. LC_COLLATE
   Collation order.
3. LC_MONETARY Monetary formatting.
4. LC_NUMERIC
   Numeric, non-monetary formatting.
5. LC_TIME Date and time formats.
6. LC_MESSAGES Formats of informative and diagnostic messages and
   interactive responses.